# Opening port 3000 EC2 Amazon web services

Tags: ubuntu, port, amazon-web-services, node.js

I am trying to use nodejs and socket.io to deliver a webapp, which use websocket on port 3000.

I have opened port 3000 on my EC2 instance in my management console by adding the inbound TCP rule to the relevant security group, however I still can't access it via public dns on my browser.

sudo netstat -tulpn doesn't show it as an open port.

What am I missing? Is there some service I need to restart or a command line I need to push to get it running?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is the port open on the node server?

> iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3000 -j ACCEPT

Check both iptables and SElinux entries